# Record / Count number of plays in HTML5 audio player

Tags: html5-audio

I'm using [audio.js](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) player.
Is it possible to record / count the number of plays ?
This is so that I can show the number of times a particular song has been played by users.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual code would be but it looks like you can use the `trackEnded` event callback. If you add an event listener to it you can increment a `playCount` that could be passed to localStorage or a data store.